# How to run Swift unit tests on Jenkins deployed on Windows Server

Tags: swift, unit-testing, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 where I installed Jenkins.

I want to run some tests that execute Swift code for our iOS app in a Jenkins pipeline.

First of all, is it possible to run such tests, since Jenkins is installed on a Windows server?

Second, is there any Jenkins plugin I can use to perform such task?
Do you know of any documentation or tutorial?

I have not been able to find anything relevant on the Internet.

Thank you very much

cghersi

Answer (score 1):

It’s possible to run Swift on windows, but to run all your iOS app’s tests (which invariably will depend on iOS specific frameworks like UIKit or SwiftUI) is only possible via the Xcode tool chain on macOS.